# Boot from USB without using legacy mode

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, live-usb

The boot from usb option only shows when booting in legacy mode. 
As I am trying to run boot-repair I need to run the system in uefi mode.

What do I need to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to boot from UEFI and that means that you go to your BIOS (press the correct key at the vendor splash screen) and pick the UEFI + USB option to boot from the boot options.

Mind that the USB might be wrongly created: UEFI is assumed for installation if the live session has a /lib/firmware/efi/  on it with the UEFI files in there.

Comment: When I boot from UEFI and pick Ubuntu I am stuck at the "Minimal BASH like line editing is supported" screen. I am trying to fix this problem by using boot-repair.

Comment: No. You pick the USB.

Comment: But it's not available, it only shows up in legacy mode...

Comment: Then check the 2nd part of my answer: make sure the USB has efi on it.

Comment: Not sure I understand this part, do you mean that these files should be present on the usb? Because in that case, it seems like they are not.

Comment: yes when they are not the USB is always in legacy mode. 2 options: add them to the current USB (but I have not found good instructions on that yet) or make a new USB but with efi this time.

Comment: Thanks for the info, it works now! I used Rufus to create the usb now which had all the relevant files.